# Using UITableViewRowAction, how to change the TableView swipeable cell buttons textcolor and Font in iOS Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Im working on TableView Right Swipeable, Im created 3 buttons(Edit,Mark Reviewed, Create Linked) in **editActionsForRowAtIndexPath**

```
 UITableViewRowAction *edit = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Edit" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                {

                                }];
edit.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.f) green:(118/255.f) blue:  (165/255.f) alpha:1.0f];
 UITableViewRowAction *markReviewed = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Mark\n Reviewed" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                              {

                              }];
 markReviewed.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.f) green:(60/255.f) blue:(84/255.f) alpha:1.0f];
 UITableViewRowAction *createLinked = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Create\n Linked" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                              {

                              }];
createLinked.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.f) green:(118/255.f) blue:(165/255.f) alpha:1.0f];
return @[edit, markReviewed,createLinked];
```

please help me to change the button text color and  text font.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can not, you can only change background color

Comment: Thanks, But How can I manage it, is there anyway to create 3 buttons at swiping?